How to detect, if a file in an iCloud or Onedrive directory is On-Disk or On-Demand?
In MacOS in some special directories for e.g. iCloud or Onedrive files can be "onDisk" or "onDemand".
In the finder you see a cloud symbol.
With the following snippet I get the content of suche a Directory.
How can I check for a file, it its fully on-disk, or just the name.
func getDirContent(){
  let startURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/name/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~bbc~Pic/Documents")
   do
   { let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: startURL,
                             includingPropertiesForKeys: [ .contentModificationDateKey, .fileSizeKey, .isRegularFileKey],
                                                options: [ .skipsHiddenFiles,
                                                           .skipsPackageDescendants],
                                           errorHandler: { (url, error) -> Bool in
                                                           print("directoryEnumerator error at \(url): ", error)
                                                           return true
                                                         }
     )!
     print("Level: \(enumerator.level)")
     
     for item in enumerator {
       
       let fileURL = item as! URL
       print("URL: >\(fileURL.absoluteString)<")
       let resourceValues = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: Set([.creationDateKey, .isDirectoryKey, .fileSizeKey, .isRegularFileKey]))
       if (resourceValues.isRegularFile!) {
         // is this file on Disk or "on Demand"

         // if let size = resourceValues.fileSize {
         // do something ....
         // }
       }
     }
   } catch
   { print(error)
   }
}

